# swift add label in the beginning and remove it once button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

this app currently starts out with a black background. I want a label that says " warning may cause a seizure " in the black background and once the screen is pressed the label should go away. this is really simple but I am new to this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemYellow,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemPink,
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemOrange,
        .magenta, .darkGray, .gray, .lightGray, .brown, .cyan
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        let color1 = self.colors.randomElement()
        let color2 = self.colors.randomElement()
        
        self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view.backgroundColor = color1 /// set to color1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/25, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .black
            self.view.backgroundColor = color2// now animate to color2, reverse, then repeat
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the great questions! Do you want something like this?

[image: Label displayed at beginning, disappears when button is pressed]

Here's the code (btw changed the duration from `1/25` to `1` because it was flashing so fast that I almost got a seizure):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemYellow,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemPink,
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemOrange,
        .magenta, .darkGray, .gray, .lightGray, .brown, .cyan
    ]
    
    var label: UILabel?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    
        let label = UILabel()
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.text = "Warning. May cause a seizure."
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        self.label = label /// assign self.label, so we can access it later
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        if let myLabel = label {
            myLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            self.label = nil /// set to nil, so we won't try to remove it again
        }
        
        let color1 = self.colors.randomElement()
        let color2 = self.colors.randomElement()
        
        self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view.backgroundColor = color1 /// set to color1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .black
            self.view.backgroundColor = color2// now animate to color2, reverse, then repeat
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that the button you press has the label that you described (which looks like the case, from your past questions).

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) { //<-- Here
    sender.isHidden = true //<-- Here
    let color1 = self.colors.randomElement()
    let color2 = self.colors.randomElement()
    
    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.view.backgroundColor = color1 /// set to color1
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/25, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.backgroundColor = color2// now animate to color2, reverse, then repeat
    }
  }
}
```

If it is a different button/label, you can hook up at `@IBOutlet` to that `UIButton/UILabel` in Interface Builder and use the same technique of `.isHidden = true` to hide it.

Comment: thank you very much ! but once the button disappears I can't change the background colors anymore by pressing the screen..it gets stuck in a loop

Comment: Seems like you have a variety of options. You could make the entire screen the button and then show/hide the title (`.setTitle("", for: .normal)`). You could make the label separate from the button (see the second part of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1/25 is too fast to be visible as anything other than a flash. That's only about 2 screen refreshes. Start with a MUCH longer duration (like 1/3 second) first, get that working, and then shorten the duration until you get the effect you are after (But I don't think you'll ever want a duration shorter than about 1/10 of a second for an animation step, and that is pushing it.)

Your code inside the animate() block sets `self.view.backgroundColor` to black, and then immediately sets it to color2. The step where you set it to black will be ignored.

Describe the effect you want?

Comment: thanks for your time. I want 2 things. first I want to be able to delete the label once the button or screen is pressed. second I want to press the button and have 2 random colors flash continuously until the button is pressed again, then 2 new random colors will flash and so on ..

Comment: you're amazing man !! sorry for the seizure lolllllll

Comment: You should pick the answer that best answers your question and click the check-mark to accept it.